# RSYNC and folder hierachcy

Tags: backup, rsync

After making a full forensic copy of a harddrive using dd, I would like to keep up with changes between the original and backup harddisc, therefore I started using rsync.

Whenever, I run

```
sync -a -v -n  --progress /media/drive1 /media/drive2
```

the command would start listing all files contained in drive1. However, only a couple of them has changed after I did DD.

Trying that on a single folder

```
sync -a -v -n  --progress /media/drive1/folder /media/drive2
```

works fine and just displays the new files in that folder - those which are not contained in /media/drive2/folder.

However, executing the command on the level of both volumes

sync -a -v -n  --progress /media/drive1 /media/drive2

does not account for the differentials, contrary to the documentation which is everywhere available, but takes all files which are already on both drives.
What is my mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way `rsync` treats its source and destination paths is easy to get wrong. When you use the command:

```
sync -a -v -n  --progress /media/drive1 /media/drive2
```

...it tries to sync the drive1 folder *into* drive2; that is, it creates and populates /media/drive2/drive1. When you add "/folder" to the source path, it works as expected because then it's trying to sync with /media/drive2/folder, which is what you want.

Fortunately, the solution is easy: add "/" to the end of the source path, which tells it to sync the *contents of* drive1 into drive2, rather than the folder itself:

```
sync -a -v -n  --progress /media/drive1/ /media/drive2
```

BTW, I'd recommend adding `--dry-run` to make sure it's doing what you want before running it "for real". You'll probably also have to delete /media/drive2/drive1.

Comment: Yes, I was dry-running it all the time, at least I thought -n flagging accounts for that. But many thanks for pointing me to the additional "/" for the first path. No way, I could have found this on my own - at least in a logical sense!